# Cambiar paleta de colores en un gráfico generado con plot_ly usando R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando cambiar el color de un sencillo gráfico que genero usando `plot_ly`, que es una librería nueva que he empezado a utilizar recientemente. El conjunto de datos df contiene tres variables, X, Y y Z. En el gráfico que obtengo, el color está asociado a Z y por defecto sale coloreado con una gama de colores rojos.

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~X, y = ~Y,
               marker = list(color = ~Z, showscale = TRUE))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se cambia la paleta de colores que viene por defecto?. He mirado en la documentación y no me queda claro. He intentado hacer el cambio manipulando `add_trace`, pero sin éxito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si consultamos la ayuda de [`plot_ly()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.9.3/topics/plot_ly), hay un parámetro útil para lo que buscas:

> **colors** Either a colorbrewer2.org palette name (e.g. "YlOrRd" or "Blues"), or a vector of colors to interpolate in hexadecimal
> "#RRGGBB" format, or a color interpolation function like colorRamp().

Es decir, puedes usar alguna de las paletas predefinidas de [colorbrewer2.org](https://colorbrewer2.org/), que eventualmente podrías consultar así:

```
library("RColorBrewer")
display.brewer.all()
```

O bien, un vector de colores en hexadecimal, por ejemplo:

```
colores <- c('#a6cee3','#1f78b4','#b2df8a','#33a02c','#fb9a99','#e31a1c','#fdbf6f',
             '#ff7f00','#cab2d6')
```

O incluso, usar `colorRampPalette()` para generar un conjunto `N` colores

```
colores <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))(14)
```

Esto al menos es lo que se indica en la documentación. Ahora bien, creo que entiendo lo que buscas, pero esto:

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~X, y = ~Y,
               marker = list(color = ~PR, showscale = TRUE))
```

no sería la forma indicada de hacerlo, sino más bien algo así:

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, 
               x = ~X, 
               y = ~Y,
               color = ~PR,
               colors = "Set1" # Así configuramos la palea de colores
)
```

Configuar `colors` de alguna de las formas que te he comentado para probar distintas variantes.

Comment: Gracias @Patircio Moracho he comenzado a usar recientemente esta librería porque las visualizaciones que permite son muy atractivas. Sin embargo, encuentro la documentación y la estructura del código más farragosa que la de ggplot. O quizá simplemente es que ya me acostumbré a ggplot. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @pyring, no sé si sabías pero `plotly` es capaz de "entender" las gráficas `ggplot` sin problemas, puedes seguir construyendo todo con `ggplot`  guardar la gráfica en una variable y pasarsela a la función `ggplotly()`. Saludos.

Comment: pues la verdad no lo sabía, pero me acabas de dar una alegría.

Answer (score 0):

list(color = "#00FFFF")

Mira estos dos enlaces: https://plotly.com/r/colorscales/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349377/use-rgb-customers-colors-by-group-in-r-plotly

Comment: Si entiendo bien, esto me permitiría pintar la gráfica con un solo color. Pero no cambiar la paleta de gama de colores. Por defecto aparece en una gama de rojos, pero no sé cómo cambiarla para que por defecto la variable Z sea coloreada con otra gama de colores diferentes.